# Phonegap-Cookies-Plugin issue

Tags: angularjs, cordova, firebase, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework

I am trying to code a cross-platform app using cordova and firebase while using the Phonegap-Cookies-Plugin to clear my cookies from my InAppBrowser but when I am using the given example :

```
window.cookies.clear(function() {
   console.log('Cookies cleared!');
});
```

**My console is saying : Cannot read property 'clear' of undefined.**

I wanted to know if you had any ideas ?

**Details :** I already reinstalled the platforms and plugins to be sure it's well installed. As you will see in my extract, I am also using AngularJS, Ionic and Ui Router.

**Ref :** https://github.com/bez4pieci/Phonegap-Cookies-Plugin
          https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

**Extract from my code :**

```
angular.module('starter')

.controller('ProfileCtrl', function($rootScope,$scope,$state, UserSrv, $ionicViewSwitcher, $ionicModal)
{
    $scope.deconnectFB = function(){
        $rootScope.loggedInUser='false';
        window.cookies.clear(function() {
            console.log('Cookies cleared!');
        });
        $rootScope.ref.unauth();
        $state.go("welcome");
};
```

Comment: I also tried with $window with injecting it in into the tube but I end up with the same issue

Comment: And i am using the function : authWithOAuthPopup to log in

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do here? What are you using the cookie plugin for? Why are you trying to clear them? etc.

Comment: I am trying to clean the cookies to allow the user to log in with various accounts because now my inappbrowser is remembering the user and firebase is automatically connecting to the last profile via authWithOAuthRedirect. ( connecting to facebook ) 
I think you are aware of this problem with the inappbrowser because Jacob Wenger is also using this plugin on his old tutorial 

https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-07-25-ionic-simple-login.html

Comment: I see, understood. Have you included the requisite `cordova.js`, `ionic.js` or `phonegap.js` in your app prior to these calls? Can you successfully use any other installed PhoneGap plugins? It sounds like the plug-in was not installed or was not included successfully.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it's well installed. I have the confirmation every time I am building and everytime I am using "ionic plugin ls". I also removed and readded the platforms after having added the plugin. I am also using the plugins InAppBrowser and Geolocation which are perfectly working...